# Button in foreground over ios desktop and any other application

Tags: ios, accelerometer, user-experience

Is it possible on iOS to have a button in foreground coming from my app, being constantly displayed on foreground (foreground of iOS desktop as well as over other apps ?

We already implemented it on Android but after some researches we just figured out it will be much more complicated on iOS. Did someone already done that ?

If it is not possible, could it be possible to use accelerometer to request the same action that would be within that button.

For instance by hitting the button we would like to open a tweet on native app twitter. If display of that button in foreground is impossible we would eventually replace that `'press'` by a `'hit'` on the side of the phone firing the request instead of pressing the button itself using accelerometer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not handle something when you app is killed, you can add buttons only in your application, you actually need to know that in iOS your code run's only when your app is in foreground(opened) and background(when tapped home button, but not killed), when your app is terminated(closed) only thing you can do send push notification from server and thats all. So answer - 1) No, 2) No